# Incorrect transformation when using pyproj

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, pyproj, pyshp

I am using pyproj to work with `shp` files and am relatively new to GIS. I am tryign to visualize the `shp` data, but am having a problem as I am incorrectly transforming the coordionates.

Here is an example from my code:

```
import shapefile
shp = shapefile.Reader(filePath)  # .shp file
rec = shp.shapeRecords()[0]
x, y = rec.shape.points[0]
```

Now, the resulting `x` and `y` are in utm format. For plotting, I want to convert to (lat,lon). I am using the following:

```
import pyproj
p = pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:3857', proj='utm', zone=36N, ellps='WGS84')
p(x,y,inverse=True)
```

But this gives me incorrect (lat,lon) coordinates. the point in question is close to the Syrian-Israeli border, and has the raw value of `(3970162.65625, 3853896.40625)`. But running `p(x,y,inverse=True)` gives the (lat,lon) coordinates of `67.809, 29.709`, which turns out to be around Finland.

Any ideas why this transformation is wrong? I checked for the zone in [here](http://coordtrans.com/coordtrans/guide.asp?section=SupportedCountries). And I am pretty sure the other parameters are correct as well. The shp file was created by exporting from ArcGIS desktop's ArcMap.

**Edit in response to comment:**

Here is the `.prj` file:

```
PROJCS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere",
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS_1984",
6378137.0,298.257223563]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],
PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",0.0],
PARAMETER["Auxiliary_Sphere_Type",0.0],
UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Comment: EPSG 3857 isn't a UTM projection, Zone 36 north is EPSG:32636. The EPSG code should be all you need... proj, zone, ellips are all specified in the EPSG. Those numbers don't look right for UTM, are you sure it's UTM and not web mercator or Lamberts?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I am not sure, is there perhaps a way to check this?

Comment: Where do the points come from? You say shapefile so there should be a .prj file with it, open in Notepad (or your favorite text editor) and copy/paste the whole string into your question. If there's not a prj file then you need to find out from the agency or people you got the data from what spatial reference they used to store the data in.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I edited the question with the .prj text

Comment: there is an example https://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/ in your case p1 = Proj(init='epsg:3857') p2 = Proj(init='epsg:4326') to project from Web Mercator to WGS84 geographic.

Comment: Thank you. Just to let others know: the last comment by @MichaelMiles-Stimson is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Now you can put that into an answer for your own question with some of your working code for users with a similar problem.

Comment: I will do that. But I notice that now my plot has just different scale, but still ugly to view. I think I am looking for a projection into cartesian coordinates, that I can work with in `matplotlib`. Sorry for the confusion, I am new to GIS.

Comment: That would be another question. The rules here are *one question per question*, if you have another then please ask on a new thread. When you say 'cartesian' what do you mean? Mathematically cartesian coordinates are X, Y (optional Z) which can describe just about any spatial reference.

Comment: I am lacking on the terminology. I will express it in a new thread with a figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future users, here is some of my code. It might be helpful for a jumpstart.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import pyproj
import shapefile

shp = shapefile.Reader(filePath)
recs = shp.shapeRecords()

p1 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3857') 
p2 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')

for j in range(1,len(recs)):
    rec = recs[j]
    verts = np.array(rec.shape.points)

    xin = np.array(verts)[:,0]
    yin = np.array(verts)[:,1]

    y,x = pyproj.transform(p1,p2,x=xin,y=yin)
    verts =  tuple(zip(y,x))
    poly = Polygon(verts, facecolor='red', edgecolor='0')
    ax.add_patch(poly)  

ax.autoscale_view()

plt.show()
```