# Bizarre Long, Lat coordinates....don't make sense at all

Tags: coordinate-system, reprojection-mathematics

I've tried everything I can including all the possible projection transformations....these lng, lat's make no sense.

Here is a sample coord with its disclosed mapping.  The point is in British Columbia, Canada (I'm mapping the BC Wildfires presently underway).

**(1302838.303, 517054.973) ----> EPSG_4326 - WGS84**

I'm trying to get this to Google Maps projection and plotted....which I know is EPSG 3857.

Here is the source of the data, you can see that they have an actual Google Map with this data plotted, so it's not incorrect.  They even show the

"Extent:  Latitude: 48.0° to 60.0°, Longitude: -139.5° to -113.5°"....but those coordinates make no sense.   I even tried every possible conversion on the epsg.io Transform coordinates tool (http://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=3857) and got nowhere.

Comment: Here is the SOURCE DATA:
https://catalogue.data.gov.bc.ca/dataset/fire-perimeters-current

Comment: Are you using the shapefiles (e.g. prot_current_fire_points)? If so, you can check the .prj file. It says the coordinate system is NAD_1983_BC_Environment_Albers.

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question.  All critical information should be in the question body.

Comment: What *exactly* did you download and where does it say the coordinates are long/lat?

Comment: Thank you @user3057391 and @cag! The .prj file advice helped incredibly ----> it is indeed EPSG 3005. Indeed it is then total nonsense that the BC Govt website (data source) says it is EPSG 4326. It wasted a ton of time for me. I'm coding in Python and need to convert the coords numerically....I can use pyproj. So QGIS won't work, as I need to use a Python module/library. Any advice on how to get this into Google Maps coords?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org) (free and open source) to load the data and reproject it to WGS84 if is what you need. I've downloaded the 'prot_current_fire_points' shape and open it on QGIS, it says is using the EPSG:3005 (NAD83/BC Albers).

By loading the OSM in the background (with the Openlayers Plugin) the ubication seems to be correct.
[image: Points over OSM]

Now, if you want to reproyect it, you can use the 'Processing toolbox' and search for 'Reproject layer'.

[image: Reproject tool]

Select the layer and the Target CRS to EPSG:4326. If you want so save it to shapefile (or other format), clic on the three dots button at the end of the [Save to temporary file] text box and select 'Save to file'. Finally, run the process to generate the new file.

Comment: Thank you @user3057391 and @cag!

The .prj file advice helped incredibly ----> it is indeed EPSG 3005.

Indeed it is then total nonsense that the BC Govt website (data source) says it is EPSG 4326.  It wasted a ton of time for me.

**I'm coding in Python and need to convert the coords numerically....I can use pyproj.  So QGIS won't work, as I need to use a Python module/library.**

Any advice on how to get this into Google Maps coords?

Comment: Well, that changes the question A LOT! It's important that you include in the question witch technology/language are you using. Check out this answer, wich makes a projection using pyproj: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/236703/4097